# Как взять найденный элемент list с помощи linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

Очень плохо знаком с linq с#, и посмотрев примеры не нашел такого которого хотел бы я.
Вот пример кода:

```
foreach(string word in listWord
    .Select(text => text.Trim().ToLower())
    .Where(t => setting.worldSerach.All(t2 => t.Contains(t2))))
{
    words[word.Replace('{', '-').Replace('}','-')] = words.TryGetValue(word, out int count) ? count + 1 : 1;
}
```

Т.е как я понимаю, делаю Where, выбираю слово подходящие под условие.
В `(List<string>)` **worldSerach** есть слова. Если в тексте есть одно или более из слов, то в `(Dictionary<string, int>)` **words** записываю найденное слово + 1.
Я хочу записывать не найденное слово, из **listWord**, а найденное слово из **worldSerach**. Т.е из `List<string>` **setting.worldSerach**

Какие есть варианты? Прошу помощи!

**UPD 1.0**
Была ошибка в имени : **setting.worldSerach** в место world - word.
И в место `listWord` - `listLine`

Я хочу сделать следующие:
У меня есть список строк, разных маленьких и больших.
Потом есть коллекция, символов, слов или мини приложений, хоть что угодно.
На данный момент код выполняет следующие:

1. Проходиться по массиву.
2. Находит каждую строку и проверяет с помощи Where - есть ли там слова находящийся в коллекции.
3. Если есть то записывает в Dictionary[Найденный текст] + 1.

Вот код в консоли:

```
       Dictionary<string, int> words = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        string[] listText =
        {
            "Привет Мир!",
            "Кто то тут был!",
            "Вопросительный знак?",
            "Еще какой то дополнительный текст"
        };
        List<string> searchWord = new List<string>();
        searchWord.Add("!");
        searchWord.Add("!");

        foreach (string line in listText
            .Where(t => searchWord.All(t2 => t.Contains(t2))))
        {
            words[line.Replace('{', '-').Replace('}', '-')] = words.TryGetValue(line, out int count) ? count + 1 : 1;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Результат: ");
        foreach (var res in words)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - {1}", res.Key, res.Value);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Убрал Select, и переписал немного Where, в место All -> Any.
Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут отображаются количество строк в котором есть символы `!`,`?`.
Но мне нужно взять не количество строк, а количество символов найденных в этих строк.

Comment: Объясните что вы хотите, а мы объясним как это сделать. На текущий момент сложно понять что вы хотите по вопросу и по коду тоже

Comment: Этот код похож на то что он считает слова, но выглядит очень странно. Сделайте маленький запускаемый консольный пример, выложите код, скажите, что дано и какой результат вы ожидаете. А пока ваш вопрос непонятен. Даже непонятно, этот код работает или нет. `word` - "слово", `world` - "мир", у вас здесь про что именно?

Comment: Вы хотите посчитать сколько раз встречается указанное слово в List<string>? Это можно сделать через `list.Where(x => x.ToLower().Equals(needWord.ToLower())).Count`

Comment: Изменил тему как вы и просили. Возможно вы поймете

Comment: @Frehzy спасибо за подсказку. Буду сейчас пробовать

Comment: Всё равно не понятно, что хотите-то? *Я хочу сделать следующее:...*, напишите следующее: что на вход, что на выход хотите получить. Сейчас слабо понятно, что именно вам нужно

Comment: Вместо скриншота опубликуйте код текстом, чтобы любой желающий мог его скопировать и запустить. Тогда вам быстро помогут.

Comment: `Serach` - имелось в виду `Search`? Исправьте названия

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  сделано. Да, именно `Search` - торопился и вот ошибка

Comment: @Aarnihauta Я наверное не очень хорошо объясняю. Но вот Frehzy сказал именно то что мне нужно.
Мне в место того что бы считать количество найденных слов в массиве нужно  считывать количество найденных слов в List<string>. Т.е сколько есть совпадений в массиве со словами  List<string>.
Пока что его код я не могу выполнить.

Answer (score 1):

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var textList = new List<string>
        {
            "Привет !Ми?р!",
            "Кто то тут был!",
            "Вопросительный знак?",
            "Еще какой то дополнительный текст"
        };
        var searchWordlist = new List<string>
        {
            "!",
            "?"
        };
        
        var result = textList.CountNumberOfCharacters(searchWordlist);

        foreach (var word in result)
            Console.WriteLine($"Word: {word.Item1}. Count: {word.Item2}");
    }
}

internal static class ListExtention
{
    public static IEnumerable<(string, int)> CountNumberOfCharacters(this List<string> list, List<string> searchWordlist)
    {
        foreach (var text in list)
        {
            var count = text.Count(x => searchWordlist.Contains($"{x}"));
            yield return (text, count);
        }
    }
}
```

Если будет не лень - создайте класс вместо Tuple, в котором создайте 2 свойства - 1 хранит в себе слово, 2 хранит в себе количество вхождений символа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хм, а зачем все эти сложности? 1. Вы своим методом `XXX` изобрели `.Select()`. 2. `Tuple<string, int>` уже по сути давно так не пишут, ибо `(string, int)`. 3. `x.ToString()` -> `$"{x}"`, в новом .NET проблем с этим нет, хотя тут вообще лучше коллекцию делать из char или string сразу. 4. `XXX(textList, searchWordlist)` - тогда уж лучше ваш метод сделать методом расширения и писать `textList.XXX(searchWordlist)`, более понятней будет. 5. Названия переменных весьма странные, про `XXX` молчу, фиг с ним, а вот `....list`, смысл, если это и так `List<T>`?